# how find the distinct wildcard in where statement mysql

Tags: mysql

```
 CREATE TABLE table1
        (`id` int not null auto_increment primary key, `data` char(3),`subject` varchar(250)) ;

INSERT INTO table1
    (`id`, `data`,`subject`)
VALUES
    (1, 'xa','aad'),
    (2, 'ya','aac'),
    (3, 'yc','aae'),
    (4, 'zb','aaf'),
    (5, 'yb','aag'),
    (6, 'xc','aah'),
    (7, 'za','aai');
```

As shown in the table how can find all the ***distinct values which starts with the first letter in data column***

for eg:

```
select * from table1 where data like '%x%' limit 1;
select * from table1 where data like '%y%' limit 1;
select * from table1 where data like '%z%' limit 1;
```

into **one single query** and get this output as shown below

**output**

```
1, 'xa', 'aad'
2, 'ya','aac'
3, 'zb','aaf'
```

[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/08235)

Comment: Can't you just do those queries with limit 1? Thats how i understand what you want atleast..

Comment: @Zulatin but all in one query as shown in the output

Comment: `UNION`? Also, if you want just those that start with x, y and z, you want to remove the leading wildcard so: `LIKE 'x%'`...

Comment: Row '3 zb' doesn't exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combination `DISTINCT` and `LEFT`? But don't forget that indexes aren't use with this approach.

```
SELECT distinct(LEFT(`data`, 1)) first_letter, id, `data`, subject 
FROM table1
GROUP BY first_letter
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/08235/5/0

Comment: Distinct isn't a function, and it would never be used in conjunction with a group by clause.

Answer (score 1):

Made it in single query

```
select 
  id,
  data,
  LEFT(group_concat(subject order by id),LOCATE(',',group_concat(subject order by id)) - 1),
from table1
group by SUBSTRING(data, 1, 1)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `UNION`:

```
(select * from table1 where data like '%x%' limit 1) 
UNION ALL
(select * from table1 where data like '%y%' limit 1) 
UNION ALL
(select * from table1 where data like '%z%' limit 1) ;
```

[updated fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/08235/9)

Note that: You have to enclose each query in `()` in order to limit work for each query, other wise you will get only one row not three rows.

Also note that, `'%z%'` will give you those values that contains `z` in any position not only the first character. You need to use `LEFT(data, 1) = 'z'` instead:

```
(select * from table1 where LEFT(data, 1) = 'x' limit 1 ) 
UNION ALL
(select * from table1 where  LEFT(data, 1) = 'y' limit 1) 
UNION ALL
(select * from table1 where  LEFT(data, 1) = 'z' limit 1 )
```

[updated fiddle 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/08235/10)

Answer (score -1):

You can use subquery to get first `id` per group

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE id IN (
select min(id) from table1
where data like '%x%'
OR data like '%y%'
OR data like '%z%'
GROUP BY left(data, 1)
)
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c8813a/7/0).